# A small exercise on polynomial rings

Tags: polynomials

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero and let $S=k[x,y,z]$. Suppose that $f,g\in S$ are such that $x$ divides $yf + zg$. Can we conclude that $x$ divides $f$ and, of course, $g$? Any hint?

Thank you!

Comment: Let $f=z$ and $g=-y$, then $yf+zg=0$ is divisible by $x$, but neither $f$ nor $g$.

Comment: Of course, thank you.